# What does the phone icon in call logs on iOS mean?

Tags: call, phone.app

In this screenshot, the number marked in red has an icon. Is this a Incoming or an outgoing call?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

See the little phone icon (with the arrow going out) next to the number?  That indicates it was an outgoing call.

**An incoming call will have no icon.**

I can't tell you how the call was made.  Even calls that contain errors (mis-dialed numbers) will be in this list so maybe it was someone calling the wrong number?

Comment: Ok, clear, so there is nopossibility this is an incoming or incoming cancelled call ? Just to be sure ....

Comment: The icon _indicates it was an outgoing call. An incoming call will have no icon_. This is fact, not conjecture.